# why don't Leadbolt Icon ads show up?

Tags: android, leadbolt

I am trying to integrate [Leadbolt](http://www.leadbolt.com/) icon ads into an Android app.  I followed the How-to guide: http://www.leadbolt.com/docs/Leadbolt_android_app_guide_v304.pdf .  Here's the relevant code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- LeadBolt -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```

The onCreate for the launcher Activity:

```
String leadboltIconId = Application.getInstance().getLeadboltIconId();
Log.d(TAG, "leadboltIconId: >" + leadboltIconId + "<");
AdController adController = new AdController(this, leadboltIconId, this);
adController.loadIcon();
```

"leadboltIconId" is filled correctly.  Here is a ss of the config screen:

[image]

and the details screen:
[image]

I am using an emulator with 2.3.3 on it.  It also doesn't work on my HTC Incredible with CM7 ( 2.3.3 ).  There are no errors in the log.  The activity implements AdListener and none of the methods are ever called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change this line:

```
AdController adController = new AdController(this, leadboltIconId, this);
```

to

```
AdController adController = new AdController(
    getApplicationContext(), leadboltIconId);
```

Also, please note the 3 variable is not needed when running App Icons as App icons will not trigger any event listeners. You need to use the Application Context rather than Activity for App Icons and Notifications. Activity is needed for App Ads.

Comment: this worked.  But i shouldn't have to ask about it.  The parameter should be of type "Application" not "Context".  Or there should be an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: where to find library of leadbolt for android?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with the Ad Icon. I also noticed someone else posting this problem on the Leadbolt Q&A forum recently. There might be a problem with Leadbolt's side, however they fail to communicate this to us...